# Is there a way in Razor Pages to render a partial from a string, rather than it's name

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I would like to dynamically render partials from a string I build up, or store separately, is there a way I can do something like the following in Razor Pages:

```
@Html.PartialFromString("<h1>McHello @ViewData[\"Title\"]</h1>")
```

I can see that there is @Html.Raw..., but this only seems to deal with static HTML, i.e. no @ supported.

Comment: Razor files are (normally) transpiled from `.cshtml` into `.cs` and then compiled as part of the rest of the `.csproj` - they don't work like PHP's `eval()`. [You can do runtime compilation of Razor files from-disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#enable-runtime-compilation-conditionally) and presumably also in-memory strings, but I don't believe it's officially supported.

Comment: Why do you want to build up Razor syntax dynamically? What problem are you trying to solve?